# How to color a group of cells in a matrix when plotting with "plot.matrix"

Tags: r, matrix, plot

There is a matrix with values like

```
2   3   4
4   9   16
8   18  32
```

I am trying to plot this matrix with the help of this package [ https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plot.matrix/vignettes/plot.matrix.html#missing-values-and-out-of-range-matrix-entries ]

I want to color it for each specific cell using some test case. For example:

```
For each cell in the matrix,
 if ( number == prime )
  then color that particular cell as blue.
```

But the library only gives the option of using breaks which color according to a set of ranges.

Is it possible to color based on the values within each cell according to some formula?? Can there be some workaround? OR may be if not through this library then some other way in which this can be done?

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would use ggplot for this - specifically, `geom_tile`. First, to fulfil your needs, we need to recreate your matrix:

```r
mat <- matrix(c(2, 4, 8, 3, 9, 18, 4, 16, 32), 3)

mat
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    2    3    4
#> [2,]    4    9   16
#> [3,]    8   18   32
```

Next, we need a function that can test whether each entry is prime:

```
is.prime <- function(x) 
{
  sapply(x, function(n) {
    n == 2L || all(n %% 2L:ceiling(sqrt(n)) != 0)
  })
}
```

Now we can `melt` your matrix into a dataframe using library `reshape2` and add a column specifying whether each number is prime:

```r
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

df <- melt(mat)

df$is_prime <- is.prime(df$value)
```

The resulting data frame looks like this, representing our original matrix with one column each for the original row number, the original column number, the value the cell at that location contained, and our new column specifying whether that value is prime:

```r
head(df)
#>   Var1 Var2 value is_prime
#> 1    1    1     2     TRUE
#> 2    2    1     4    FALSE
#> 3    3    1     8    FALSE
#> 4    1    2     3     TRUE
#> 5    2    2     9    FALSE
#> 6    3    2    18    FALSE
```

Now we can plot with the full versatility of `ggplot2`:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(Var1, Var2, fill = is_prime)) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), size = 10) +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "deepskyblue"), guide = guide_none())
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, Is it also possible to add another color to the cells in addition to the above so that if the cell is a whole number it is highlighted with red color?  I tried with another geom_tile but that overrides the previous one...do I have to divide the data  somehow and feed it to ggplot separately?

Comment: @harsh the secret is to have a single column for the fill value. This can be a character or factor column with whatever you like in it. For example, you could make all even numbers contain the string "is even", the whole numbers with "is whole", the prime numbers with "is prime". As long as you can define the mathematical function that subsets the appropriate rows (as I did with "is_prime")